# Updating certain values in a MATERIALIZED VIEW

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I have created a materialized view and now want to replace a certain value in one of the columns.
How can I do that?
Perhaps I should use `INSERT INTO`, but I do not really know how to use this.

The road status value I want to replace is a BLANK and not a *NULL* value.

My code is:

```
UPDATE konflikt.vejstatus_dissolve
SET roadstatus = 'Not mentioned'
WHERE
   roadstatus = '' ;
```

Actually, the neatest thing would be if the update of data could be integrated into the materialized view.

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW konflikt.vejstatus_dissolve AS
       SELECT row_number() over () as gid,
       ST_UNION(the_geom)::geometry(MULTILINESTRING,25832) as the_geom,vejstistatus
       FROM_05_veje_trafik.vejstatus
       GROUP BY roadstatus;
```

What do I need to do?

Comment: It is *not* legal to update the contents of a materialized view outside the DDL to manage them.  Have you tried to `DROP` and recreate the view?  That's the safest way to deal with a changing schema on the source table (`ALTER` works under some cases).  If you've only tweaked table contents, then `REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW ...` may suffice.

Comment: @ Vince Thanks. Is it not possible to replace a certain value in a column while you are running the CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW?
Maybe I could use CREATE TABLE instead. Would that make it easier?

Comment: If you can't change the source table, you can use a `CASE` to alter column contents; CREATE TABLE would have the *same issue*. At this point, your question is not GIS-centric, it's a database theory problem with how MATERIALIZED VIEW operates.

Answer (score 1):

If you're able to alter the source data, that would be a good place to start.

```
UPDATE konflikt.source_table
SET roadstatus = 'Not mentioned'
WHERE
   roadstatus = ''
```

If that isn't possible, adding a CASE statement to the roadstatus column in the materialized view is another option:

```
create materialized view konflikt.vejstatus_dissolve as
select
    row_number() over () as gid
    , ST_UNION(the_geom)::geometry(MULTILINESTRING  , 25832) as the_geom
    , vejstistatus FROM_05_veje_trafik.vejstatus
    , case when roadstatus = '' then 'Not Mentioned' end as roadstatus
group by
    roadstatus;
```

Since you're using a materialized view, rather than a standard view, the extra processing will get absorbed in the 'refresh' process rather than when it is used, which is nice.